# Sh shell scripting optional arguments not getting read

Tags: shell, sh

In my shell script, I am reading two optional parameters.
The first parameter is not getting read.  Given below is the code:

```
#! /bin/sh  
while getopts "f:c:" opt;  
do  
case "${opt}" in  
f) file=${OPTARG}   
echo "" "File Name: ${file}"  
;;  
c) str=${OPTARG}  
echo "" "String: ${str}"  
;;  
esac    
done
```

When I am running my script:

```
$ sh myscript.sh -f filename.txt -c someString
```

Output:

```
$ File Name:  
$ String: someString
```

Please let me know where am i going wrong.
I have tried all options in getopts:

```
:f:c  
f:c  
f:c:  
:f:c:
```

Comment: str=${OPTAGR} should be str={OPTARG}

Comment: oh I seem to have mis typed it here.. :P code has str=${OPTARG}

Comment: thanks Jdamian :D ..typo error killed me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code is not working because of typo
`c) str=${OPTAGR}   echo "" "String: ${str}"   ;;`  
here above you have typo in `str=${OPTAGR}` it should be `str=${OPTARG}`
I have executed below piece of code and it worked fine

```
#! /bin/sh
while getopts "f:c:" opt;
do
case "${opt}" in
f) file=${OPTARG}
echo "" "File Name: ${file}"
;;
c) str=${OPTARG}
echo "" "String: ${str}"
;;
esac
done
```

Output

```
ajay@Ajay:~$ ./new.sh -f filename.txt -c sometext
File Name: filename.txt
String: sometext
```